# Merge two arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know in PHP I can use the `array_merge` function to do this, but let's say I have two arrays like this:

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
var arr2 = [4, 5, 6];
```

How do I merge these two arrays into another array `arr3` so that it looks like this:

```
var arr3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

Thank you

Comment: [MDN Array concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: If you [google your question title](https://www.google.com/search?q=Merge+two+arrays+in+javascript), the first result is a stackoverflow question with the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
var arr2 = [4, 5, 6];

var array3 = arr1.concat(arr2 );
```